# Single loop polyhedra

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra

The [odd antiprisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiprism) are both [Eulerian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) and [polyhedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_graph), with the first implying that the edge can be represented with a single closed path.  The [Cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron) also has that property. With the rule to always go straight through a crossing, the cuboctahedron splits into 4 loops.  The odd anti-prisms each use just one loop.

The quartic 9-5 graph also uses just one loop -- the eulerian cycle can be found by always going straight through each intersection.

[image: quartic 9-5]

Are there any [triangulated graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph) with this property?

Comment: Note that $3n$-gonal antiprisms do not use just one loop: e.g. the octahedron and 9-gonal antiprism each split into three loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

This planar triangulation has an Eulerian cycle formed by going straight across each vertex:

[image]

There are 13 vertices; 7 are 4-valent, 5 are 6-valent, and 1 is 8-valent.
There are 33 edges and 22 faces.

I find it easier to work with the dual, where we need to find a circuit crossing all the edges, going straight across each face.

Here it is:

[image]

You might appreciate the graph6 code of the triangulation:

```
L|eMKF@Oz[D@M@
```

or its dual:

```
UsP@@?OC?O@_@_?_?G?B??K??O??QG?[??@c??M?
```

These can be imported into Mathematica, etc (`PlanarGraph[ImportString["…", "graph6"]]`.)

Comment: Very nice, I was hoping for a really nice canonical polyhedron, but I'm having trouble getting that to work.